# c# run batch file doen't work

Tags: c#, batch-file

I'm trying to exe batch file from C# console. 
The following code doesn't work.
I'd like to know what's wrong with my ProcessStartInfo configuration.

```
String cmd = "/C "+ path2watch + "\\batch.bat";

ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo() 
{
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    FileName = @"cmd.exe",
    Arguments = cmd,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    ErrorDialog = false
};

Process p = Process.Start(psi);
p.WaitForExit();
```

[Cd doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cz3cj.png)

Thanks

Comment: Debug it and check the output window for the error.  If needed post that up.  Also post up what the value of path2watch is.

Comment: what will `path2watch` be like and how about replace it with fixed path first?

Comment: As @JustinHarvey says - post the whole of the cmd value after the second line.

Comment: I'm using cd "path" and it doesn't change to my request path

Comment: @LeiYang  path is assigned to @"C:\\Users"

Comment: @avishle: The current directory is a process property. `cd` will only ever have an effect on the `cmd` process you launched; not the process that launched it (your C# program).

Comment: @avishle so your cmd is `cmd = "/C C:\Users\batch.bat";` ?

Comment: also please can you upload a better image?

Comment: @avishle if you want execute a bat file, only one single statement with do `Process.Start(@"C:\Users\\batch.bat");`

Comment: @Joey I'll try to change working Directory

Comment: @Lei: That depends on the user's file associations. They may just as well have set them up so batch files are opened with Notepad. In this case I'd say it's better to be explicit.

Comment: @avishle, have you defined `p`?, see answer

Answer (score 1):

The problem what that I didn't set the working directory Property.
I've set the working directory to the wanted path.
But it's still strange why cd didn't overcome "the working directory" issue

Comment: `cd` only does what you expect if your current working directory and your desired new directory are on the same drive. Your current working directory was on `d:\ ` so `cd c:\something ` did effectively nothing.